# Are all variables we use in useEffect in dependencies array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I know the how useEffect's dependencies works. However in my scenario, I should not watch the change of a prop value I use it as a condition to process flow, but I will get a react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning if I don't put it in the dependencies array.

My scenario is that if foo and fetchValue change, I want to re-run the whole fetch. Although I use bar as a condition to decide is the fechValue called, but in my business logic, the change of bar should not make re-run the block.

```
const Component = ({ foo, bar, fetchValue }) => {
  useEffect = (
    () => {
      if(foo) {
        if (bar) {
          fetchValue();
        }
      }
    },
    [foo, fetchValue] // will get a warning `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`
  )

  return <div />

}
```

Comment: this does not sound like a valid business case, more like asking for hard time debugging race conditions in the future - would you please describe more why this is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're supposed to put all variables that you use in your `useEffects` 'deps' array is not doing so can create weird issues due to stale data.

---

For example, given your use case, suppose your component props are initially `{foo: false, bar: false }` (assume `fetchValue` is some fixed function), and then they change to `{foo: true, bar: true}`.  In this case, your component will call `fetchValue` as expected.

But as another example, suppose your props change from `{foo: false, bar: false}` to `{foo: true, bar: false}` and then change to `{foo: true, bar: true}`.  In this case, `fetchValue` has not fired, despite that the props are the same as they were at the end of the previous example.

Maybe this isn't "wrong", per se, but it's certainly weird and unintuitive: ideally your component should behave consistently based on its props and it shouldn't matter what order the props changed.

---

So, yes, you can always `eslint-ignore` the deps array to allow it to be incomplete, but I'd suggest looking for another solution, personally.

It's hard to be specific without more information about the use case, but perhaps the call to `fetchValue` can be memoized so that it doesn't do anything if `foo` hasn't changed? Or perhaps `foo` and `bar` could be combined into a single prop so they change together?

Comment: "suppose your props change from {foo: false, bar: false} to {foo: true, bar: false}". It would fire there, and from what I understand, that is what @WendellLiu wants. And only that because "and then change to {foo: true, bar: true}" doesn't need to fire it.

Comment: @Robbeoli `useEffect` will fire there, but `fetchValue` will not be fired, because it's wrapped in `if(bar)` and bar is still `false`.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is true, to me this use does feel intuitive thought. I see `bar` as some state that determines if a it is ok to `fetchValue`, and `foo` as the actual trigger that needs to be true and checks if the bar state is true.

Comment: @Retsam What if `bar` is a state inside this `Component`? Do I need to add it in the dependency array to get the latest value inside `useEffect`?

Comment: @NiyasNazar Yes - the only things that you don't need to include in the deps array are things defined outside the component (e.g. imports or module level variables) and things guaranteed to be constant by React (state setters, dispatch functions, and ref objects).

Comment: @Retsam In here https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-dew-8tfdp?file=/src/App.js, `count` state is not added as a dependency in `useEffect`, but still, I get the latest value consoled when `isEnabled` changes. So is that necessary to add `count` in the dependency array here? I am getting `exhaustive-deps` warning here.

Comment: @NiyasNazar IMO, 98% of the time you should just do whatever `exhaustive-deps` says.  You can do other things with deps arrays, but they tend to be confusing an error-prone.  You're going to get the right value for `count` when the useEffect runs, even if it isn't in your deps array, but it's not going to run when count changes, which in some cases can create stale data elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The ESLint rule is there to provide safety with the `useEffect` hook.

If you're absolutely sure the value is not a dependency of `useEffect`, you can add a comment to ignore the ESLint rule: [Disabling Rules with Inline Comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments).

I would suggest adding `// eslint-disable-next-line` instead of file-wide `eslint-disable`.

Here's [more context about this by Dan Abramov](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920#issuecomment-472018256):

> > is there any way I can disable this rule specifically for places where the spread operator is used?
>
> You can always `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` if you think you know what you're doing.

Comment: Sure. I know how to disable the warning. I just want to discuss is some great implement to avoid the warning and do it in the right way.

Comment: The tool is there to catch bugs with common use cases, e.g. external variables used inside the `useEffect`, which does some optimisations to prevent calls on each re-render. What you're describing is an edge case, which the tool doesn't support, therefore you should know what you're doing and disable the rule. I have provided a comment by Dan Abramov explaining exactly this.

Answer (score -3):

Logic like that happens quite often with if statements in 'useEffect'. First of all, there is no need to add dependencies at all, you could just leave it empty.

Now there are some things you could do, either simply ignore the warning, because your code looks fine. Or reconstruct your code where `bar` is an argument of `fetchValue()`. So you're code would be:

```
const Component = ({ foo, bar, fetchValue }) => {
  useEffect = (
    () => {
      if(foo) {
        fetchValue(bar);        
      }
    },
    [foo, fetchValue] 
  )

  return <div />

}
```

And start your `fetchValue(baz)` declaration with `if(baz){ //your code}`.

Kind of cumbersome though.

You need to ask yourself, why and where do you expect foo or bar to change? Inside the component itself? Shouldn't `foo` and/or `bar` be states then with `foo` and or `bar` as defaultValues?

```
const Component = ({ foo, bar, fetchValue }) => {

  const [fooState, setFooState] = useState(foo);
  const [barState, setBarState] = useState(bar);

  useEffect = (
    () => {
      fooState && barState && fetchValue(); 
    //does the same as your code, I just prefer short circuits for these kind of things.
    },
    [fooState, fetchValue()] 
  )

  return <div />

}
```

Comment: Refactoring `fetchValue` doesn't solve anything because the code is still using the `bar` value inside the `useEffect`. I support the second part, if the value is irrelevant inside the `useEffect`, the code could probably be refactored to remove it's usage inside the `useEffect`.

Comment: Both of your examples will still raise the same linter warning, and moving props into state is not a generally good idea.  (It means that the component will completely ignore changes to those props, which is often not desired)

Comment: Maybe I did something weird then, because when I stumbled upon this warning on a similar use case, and later had to change my prop to a state for a custom delay, the warning went away: 

`useEffect(() => {
    if (toggleComponents) {
      const getElem = document.getElementById(inputId);
      const getValue = getElem.value ? getElem.value : getChecked(inputId);
      setValue(getValue);
    }
    setToggleComponents(editMode);
  }, [editMode]); `

No warnings here.

Comment: @Retsam you're making a weird argument. You say the prop changed doesn't affect the `useEffect`, but somehow it would be a problem with the state? This is getting very hypothetical, can you please provide a more concrete example on which we can expand?

Comment: @MarkoGrešak The second code snippet is a concrete example.  By copying `foo` into `fooState` on initial render, all future values of `foo` would be ignored: `useState` only reads its default value once.  (This is a completely separate issue from `useEffect`)

Comment: @Retsam I understand how `useState` works. My concerns are about the dependencies between `foo` and `bar` in the condition to call `fetchValue`, but for some reason, it doesn't impact the `useEffect`. It sounds like it's the `isLoading` state or something like that. My intuition tells me that there's a problem with the implementation or a premature optimisation here, but it's not apparent because the OP code is so vague.